# Draw icons in surfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

My application is an augmented reality application and i draw icons in the camera's [surfaceview](/questions/tagged/surfaceview). The icons where drawn according to the result of the compass. The application is locked in landscape mode. In my device which has portrait mode as default orientation and everything works fine.

Recently i tested the app in Galaxy Nexus 10 and i found that the icons were moving upwards and downwards while i was moving the device right and left respectively. The opposite happens when i move the device right and left. What is going wrong. My guess is that the nexus has a landscape default orientation and the problem comes from the remapCoordinateSystem(). I added the next code before the remapCoordinateSystem but nothing happened.

```
int defaultRotation = getRotation();
switch(defaultRotation){
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(temp, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, rotation);
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(temp, SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
                SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, rotation);
        break;
}

 private int getRotation() {
    WindowManager lWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Configuration cfg = getResources().getConfiguration();
    int lRotation = lWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    if( (((lRotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) ||(lRotation == Surface.ROTATION_180)) &&   
    (cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) ||
    (((lRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) ||(lRotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)) &&    
    (cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))){

      return Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
      }     

      return Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

getRotation() tells you how the device is rotated with respect to it's 'normal' orientation.

You need to find out what 'normal' is.
There may be a better way to do this, but a 'quick and dirty' method would be to inspect the display's width and height with display.getSize(Point point) - if the width is greater than the height, then 'normal' mode is landscape, otherwise portrait. Then you can look at rotation to see how the current rotation differs from that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe i haven't expressed my problem correctly. The problem is in the remapCoordinateSystem. There when the default orientation is landscape the icons doesn't be drawn correctly. My problem is how can i simulate the remapCoordinateSystem in the landscape orientation.

Comment: As i said, you need to know both the 'normal' orientation and the current rotation. If, for example, getRotation() reports ROTATION_0 and 'normal' orientation is landscape, you'll probably have to treat it as rotated 90 degrees.